# How to clean up captcha image?

Tags: python, opencv

i'm trying to clean up captcha and get rid of line,

original image:

[image]

this is what i have at the moment:

[image]

```
img_raw = cv2.imread("captcha.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_raw = cv2.bitwise_not(img_raw)
kernel = np.ones((0, 0), np.uint8)
img_m = cv2.morphologyEx(img_raw, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
newkernel = np.ones((0, 0), np.uint8)
img_e = cv2.erode(img_m, newkernel, iterations=1)
img_e = cv2.bitwise_not(img_e)
ret,img_final = cv2.threshold(img_e,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Trying to figure out how to improve result, would be very grateful for any tips

Comment: Even this is not good to continue, because this demand is the opposite of captcha logic. But if you really need, [this](https://github.com/nladuo/captcha-break) is the best project I have ever seen about captcha breaking.

Comment: I suggest that this activity is unethical. Attempting to subvert the CAPTCHA protection shows a lack of respect for the owner of the server, whether they are doing it to protect their bandwidth or their business

Answer (score 1):

You can try applying preprocessing steps given in -

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality

And then give the preprocessed image to Google Tesseract OCR.

I'm sure that it will recognize the captcha.